# ¿Cómo obtengo la ruta de una imagen en Xamarin?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, imagen, xamarin

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin en la cual genero un PDF con iTextSharp y tengo que ingresarle una imagen que tengo en la carpeta `./Resources/Drawable/LogoEmpresa.png`.
El problema es que no puedo obtener el path de dicha imágen.
Sé que la sentencia para crearla es:
`iTextSharp.text.Image foto = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path_imagen);`
Pero intenté con varias sentencias y no puedo obtener el path de la imágen.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? ¿Cómo obtengo el path?

---

[EDIT]

Quizás esto ayude.

Esta es la carpeta de la cual necesito obtener el path

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca todo el código que tienes, dar 1 línea ayuda poco. Saludos :D

Comment: Es que agregar más código no ayuda en nada... necesito completar la variable `path_imagen` con el path de LogoEmpresa.png, pero no sé como hacerlo y hasta ahora no encontré la solución para ello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente después de mucho tiempo pude encontrar la solución
Hay que convertir la imágen del drawable en `Bitmap` y luego guardarlo en un objeto del tipo `Image` mediante un `MemoryStream`

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.LogoEmpresa);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.ToArray();
    Image logo = Image.GetInstance(imageInByte);
    document.Add(logo);
}
```

Comment: Estas realizando **respuestas duplicadas**: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193906/c%C3%B3mo-insertar-en-un-pdf-una-imagen-de-la-carpeta-drawable-en-xamarin/235653#235653  te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Si, pasa que esta pregunta es casi lo mismo que pregunté en la pregunta que mandaste. Solo respondí las 2 para que me queden guardadas ya que muchas veces reviso las preguntas que hago cuando me olvidé como hacer algo