# ¿Cómo insertar en un PDF una imagen de la carpeta Drawable en Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, imagen, pdf, xamarin

El problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo un PDF con Xamarin Android y no puedo insertar una imagen que está en la carpeta Drawable del proyecto.

Por ahora lo único que pude hacer fue guardar la imagen que quiero en una carpeta dentro del dispositivo (LogoEmpresa.jpg) y puedo insertarla en el PDF sin problemas de la siguiente manera:

```
string path_foto = "/mnt/sdcard/TestCarpeta/LogoEmpresa.jpg";

Image foto = Image.GetInstance(path_foto);
document.Add(foto);
```

Pero si quiero poner una imágen que está dentro de la carpeta Drawable no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.

¿Tengo que obtener el Path de esa imágen? ¿Tengo que crear un objeto del tipo `Image` directamente? En cualquiera de los dos casos no sé como debería hacerlo.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente después de mucho tiempo pude encontrar la solución
Hay que convertir la imágen del drawable en `Bitmap` y luego guardarlo en un objeto del tipo `Image` mediante un `MemoryStream`

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.LogoEmpresa);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.ToArray();
    Image logo = Image.GetInstance(imageInByte);
    document.Add(logo);
}
```

Comment: **Respuesta duplicada** https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170728/c%C3%B3mo-obtengo-la-ruta-de-una-imagen-en-xamarin/235656#235656 te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos.